# DoY holidays: Chinese New Year, Passover, Cinco de Mayo

Tags: r, date

Is there an easy way to get the day of year for the above holidays? For Easter I'd do:

`dayOfYear(holiday(1992:2011, "Easter"))`

but `chron` & `timeDate` don't offer much outside of Christian/Western holidays. I need the DoY in 20 years (1992-2011) for these 3 holidays. Right now I'm looking at having to look up & enter the date for each holiday for each of the 20 years. There must be a better way!

Comment: At least, the `timeDate` package offers some non-western holidays (e.g., Japan). It offers holidays from the G7 countries and Switzerland at the moment.

Comment: do any of the results from `library("sos"); findFn("holiday")` help?

Comment: @jazzurro yes, timeDate offers _some_, but not _much_.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested the answer below. At least, some people created data for you. You want to scrape them!

Comment: @BenBolker yes, a few things in there look promising; it's going to take me a bit to figure it out, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. At least, you can scrape dates for these holidays from web. I created two data frames here. One for Chinese new year and the other for Cinco de mayo. Once you have data like this, you can process data in a way you want. I leave some work for you.

```
library(XML)

### Scrape Chinese new year

url = "http://www.chinesenewyears.info/chinese-new-year-calendar.php"

table = readHTMLTable(url)
#print(table)

chinese <- as.data.frame(table)
names(chinese) <- c("Year", "CNYD", "Animal Sign")


### Cinco de mayo

url2 <- "http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/cinco-de-mayo"

table2 = readHTMLTable(url2)
table3 = table2[2]
print(table3)

cinco <- as.data.frame(table3)
```

Comment: I was distracted making maps for a while, just finally getting back to this...Yes! I don't really know what to do after putting all this very helpful info in, but you've given me some new techniques & I appreciate that you're not handing the whole thing over. I'll keep learning!

Comment: You can learn how to arrange data frames and count dates for the holidays. I hope you learn R more!